# Is there a way to export the DDL to a file with Micronaut Data JDBC?

Tags: micronaut, micronaut-data

Let‘s say I have implemented Micronaut Data JDBC entity such as

```java
@MappedEntity
record Book(
        @Id @GeneratedValue @Nullable Long id, 
        @DateCreated @Nullable Date dateCreated,
        String title,
        int pages) {
}
```

and I would like generate the DDL representing my entities. Using the «ORM» approach, my development workflow is usually

1. Design entities
2. Export DDL to a file or console and verify my SQL expectations with the actual output (when unhappy goto 1)
3. Use DDL as a Flyway migration script
4. Configure Hibernate to verify the DDL on startup, to make sure the DB is in sync with the entity model.

For 2), in the Hibernate world I simply use [SchemaExport](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/SchemaExport.html) and this creates the dialect specific DDL such as this listing for MariaDB/MySQL below.

```sql
CREATE TABLE book (
     id UUID NOT NULL,
     date_created DATE,
     title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
     pages INT NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY(id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

So I got two questions here:

1. Is there a way to achieve the same thing using Micronaut Data JPA and export the DDL to a file or console?
2. Is there a way to validate the actual database schema on startup, to make sure the entities are in sync with the underlying database schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Micronaut Data JDBC comes with just a basic schema generator, you cannot enable the file export, but you can enable the query logging:

```
<logger name="io.micronaut.data.query" level="trace" />
```

And schema creation for your data source with `schema-generate` property:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:devDb
    driverClassName: org.h2.Driver
    username: sa
    password: ''
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: H2
```